# Parse DOM in XPCOM autocomplete component

Tags: html, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, xpcom

I know we should use JSON when receiving remote "autocomplete suggestions", but I'm forced to use standard DOM valid XHTML

I have registered component of interface `nsIAutoCompleteSearch` and using this code, to get remote XHTML via XmlHttpRequest

```
var request = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
```

so far OK. then I receive text from `request.responseText` and I need to parse DOM and get values, too overcomplicated with regexp

so here is a **code with error:**

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/feed-unescapehtml;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML)
                    .parseFragment(request.responseText, false, null, document);
```

error saying `document not defined`. Because I'm in XPCOM component, I don't have access to DOM of page or XUL overlays. This code is taken right from [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM#Safely_parsing_simple_HTML.c2.a0to_DOM)

I tried to create instance of `nsIDOMDocument` or `nsIDOMHTMLDocument` and loading them from `@mozilla.org/dom/core;1` or `@mozilla.org/dom/html;1`, but these packages doesn't seem to be accessible (error saying `Components.classes['@mozilla.org/dom/core;1'] is undefined`)

So Is there a way how to create new DOMDocument, insert `request.responseText` as HTML and then walk through its DOM structure?

function `HTMLParser` from given link is throwing same error about `document not defined`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server response is well-formed XHTML, you can just use the responseXML member of the request object.

This only works if the server is returning content type text/xml, however. Otherwise you can force the MIME type to text/xml using [XMLHttpRequest.overrideMimeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest#overrideMimeType%28%29).

A final possibility is to parse the document manually as in the original question. I would use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser) though. You can use it from an XPCOM component like this:

```
var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"].
  createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMParser);  
var doc = parser.parseFromString(aStr, "text/xml");
```

Comment: `responseXML == null` means it's not well-formed?

Comment: What is the content-type of the response? It needs to be text/xml.

Comment: `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8` and I can't change the server side

Comment: so I can't use `responseXML`, isn't it?

Comment: @Matthew: `XMLHttpRequest.overrideMimeType`?